# How to use JaveScript to imitate the custom filter/selector in this example?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I saw this custom filter on [this site](https://fgo.wiki/w/%E8%8B%B1%E7%81%B5%E5%9B%BE%E9%89%B4) (which is based on MediaWiki), and want to imitate its function on the fandom I've on for the self-learning purpose.

The table's code I'm playing with is too long, so I just put it [in here](https://a-normal-playground.fandom.com/wiki/Filter_searching_test?action=edit).

---

[2019-05-15]

After I modified my code based on @Kévin Bibollet 's example, I encountered a new problem.

Here is my js code now, just added the new function to one button for testing.

```
//different types of data from the table
const type = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-last-child(1)");
const kiwameStats = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-last-child(2)");

//buttons
const tantouFilter = document.querySelector("div#Tantou");
const wakiFilter = document.querySelector("div#Wakizashi");
const tokuFilter = document.querySelector("div#Toku");
const kiwameFilter = document.querySelector("div#Kiwame");

//path for buttons' image
const waki = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/a-normal-playground/images/b/b8/Wakizashi.png";
const wakiClicked = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/a-normal-playground/images/1/1f/Wakizashi-full.png";

//bind events to buttons
wakiFilter.addEventListener("click", () => (filter(waki, wakiClicked, type)));

//general filter method
function filter(unclickedImageSrc, clickedImageSrc, data){
    //store button's img and img's src for future use
    currentImg = this.querySelector("img");
    currentImgSrc = currentImg.getAttribute("src");
    //is the button being clicked
    isFiltered = (currentImgSrc === clickedImageSrc);
    if(isFiltered){ //button was clicked, undo the filtering
        currentImg.setAttribute("src", unclickedImageSrc);
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if(!data[i].innerHTML.includes(this.id)){ 
                data[i].parentElement.style.display = " ";
            }
        }
    }else{ //button isn't clicked, start filtering
        currentImg.setAttribute("src", clickedImageSrc);
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if(!data[i].innerHTML.includes(this.id)){ 
                data[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put them into my common.js and try it on the [test page](https://a-normal-playground.fandom.com/wiki/Filter_searching_test), my console says *Error: JavaScript parse error: Parse error: Missing ) in parenthetical in file 'User:somebody/common.js' on line 16* which is the line that bind the event listener to the button 
(**wakiFilter.addEventListener("click", () => (filter(waki, wakiClicked, type)));**)

Then I threw the code into the console, and after I clicked the button, I got: 
**TypeError: this.querySelector is not a function**.

Not sure what caused that. Am I writing my arrow function wrongly or... ?

---

[2019-05-14]

I did figure out how to use `addEventListener()` to filter certain columns out with one click. Added to two button for testing purpose:

```
//type filter
var type = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-last-child(1)");

//for tantou
const tantouFilter = document.getElementById("Tantou");
tantouFilter.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    for(i = 0; i < type.length; i++){
    if(!type[i].innerHTML.includes(tantouFilter.id)){
        type[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
//for wakizashi
const wakiFilter = document.getElementById("Wakizashi");
wakiFilter.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    wakiFilter.innerHTML = "[[File:Wakizashi-full.png|30px|link=]]";
    for(i = 0; i < type.length; i++){
    if(!type[i].innerHTML.includes(wakiFilter.id)){
        type[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

In the second function, I tried to change the image of that button at the same time, but what I got is:

[Before clickling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/209Ya.png)

[After clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rykrx.png)

For now what I want to know are:

-**How to change the image of the button once clicking?**

-**How to undo this filtering with the second click on the same button?**

And is it possible to reformat that filter function so all the buttons can use the same function?

By the way, I was using [my personal common.js](https://a-normal-playground.fandom.com/wiki/Special:MyPage/common.css) for testing, because on Fandom wiki-wide common.js requires time to be checked by them before publish.

If you want to play with the code, just copy and paste my code into your personal common.js.

Comment: Can you explain what is doing the filter on the link you shared? It seems that I am not able to understand japanese correctly...

Comment: @KévinBibollet oh the filter is hidden in the toggled div on the top. Expand it and you can see these visual filter options. Basically if one image/button is click, the columns matched this button will remain on the table, other will be hidden. If click this image/button second time, the previous filter(?) action will be cancelled. Multiple image/button can be selected at the same time. The table display all the result in default. Hope my poor English can explain it's function well. XD

Comment: That's understandable. You don't need jQuery for that (jQuery is a library of JS after all). Does the line you wrote is the only thing you did so far? Or did you try something else?

Comment: @KévinBibollet sorry for the late reply, I spend some time to play with the codes and got some progress, just added then into my question section, plz check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not updating because you inserted a "*Fandom*" tag to replace the HTML of your element.

It was a nice idea at first, but you need to know that, let's say "*Fandom pages*", are certainly converted to HTML at server-side, and that your browser receive only the HTML. I am not really sure of what I just said, but I guess that's the process.

Explained simply, when you add "*Fandom*" tags after page loading, there are not translated to HTML, because the template engine is not called.

So, in order to update your image, there is probably a `<img>` tag in the element that gets the event listener. It is the `[src]` attribute of that image element you need to update.

After looking to your page DOM tree, I think you'll have to find out the correct image URLs by yourself.

---

Now, to answer your question:

- You can get the value of an element's attribute with [`HTMLElement#getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
- You can update an element attribute's value with [`HTMLElement#setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

And with a `if` statement, you can check which picture is currently displayed, then choose the picture to show instead.

In order to have a unique function for all your filters, just make it and use it in your event listener.

```js
document.querySelector('#Tantou').addEventListener('click', function() {
  filter(this, 'url/to/tantou.png', 'url/to/tantou-filtered.png');
});

document.querySelector('#Wakizashi').addEventListener('click', function() {
  filter(this, 'url/to/wakizashi.png', 'url/to/wakizashi-filtered.png');
});

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} clickedElement - The element that triggered the event.
 * @param {string} imageSrc - The URL of the picture when it is NOT active/clicked.
 * @param {string} imageSrcFiltered - The URL of the picture when it is active/clicked.
 */
function filter(clickedElement, imageSrc, imageSrcFiltered) {
  const types = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-last-child(1)"),
  // Gets the <img> tag.
    imageElement = clickedElement.querySelector('img'),
  // Gets the current [src] attribute's value of the <img>.
    currentImageSrc = imageElement.getAttribute('src'),
  // It is filtered if the current image URL is the same as the one when it is filtered.
    isFiltered = (currentImageSrc === imageSrcFiltered);

  // If filtered, displays the lines.
  if (isFiltered) {
    // Replaces the image URL.
    imageElement.setAttribute('src', imageSrc);
    // ---- Code snippet testing purpose here!
    imageElement.setAttribute('alt', imageSrc.split('/').pop());

    for(let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
      if (!types[i].innerHTML.includes(clickedElement.id)) {
        // Sets a CSS style to an empty string to reset its value.
        types[i].parentElement.style.display = '';
      }
    }
  } // If not, hides the lines.
  else {
    // Replaces the image URL.
    imageElement.setAttribute('src', imageSrcFiltered);
    // ---- Code snippet testing purpose here!
    imageElement.setAttribute('alt', imageSrcFiltered.split('/').pop());

    for(let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
      if (!types[i].innerHTML.includes(clickedElement.id)) {
        types[i].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Tantou">
  <img src="url/to/tantou.png" alt="tantou.png">
</div>

<div id="Wakizashi">
  <img src="url/to/wakizashi.png" alt="wakizashi.png">
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>A column</th>
      <th>Column checked by filters</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Tantou</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>OtherFilter</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Wakizashi</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, you could simplify even more this function, but I don't want to give you too much things to assimilate at once.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I played my codes with your example, but encounter a new problem, might have the relationship with the arrow function (I guess?). Would you mind to check it out when you have time? Already update the code in the question section.

Comment: Mmh yeah, I probably wrote it a bit to fast... Try to replace the arrow function by a normal one: `('click', function() { filter(...); })`

Comment: With the arrow one, the keyword `this` didn't reference the right element (it referenced the `window` object... and that"s not what you want). I remove my explaination about this in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I rechecked my code, there were many things wrong... (I didn't really test it when I posted). This time, I made a runnable code snippet with a simple HTML, you can test and see that that seems to work.

Comment: The main wrong thing was *again* with `this`. As we use a anonymous function for our event listener, we need to give the clicked element winthin the parameters.

Comment: My code works well now! Thank your for all the codes and the detailed explanation on them, I really learn a lot from these!